# Selection sort using Ada

Tags: ada

How would I go about implementing the use of [*selection sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) for an array of integers, in order of ascending value? I believe the syntax would include a for loop but I'm not certain how the syntax quite works.

```
for I in 1..20 loop
   TempLowest : Integer := 99999;
   if Value(I) < TempLowest then
      Value(I) := TempLowest;
   end if;
end loop;
```

I imagine that it is something like this, but I don't quite understand how this would organize my array in order from descending to ascending. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it might help, if you described the algorithm with an *approximation* of Ada, and worried less about the syntax.  Right now, you're trying to create an array of 20 `99999`s (which technically is sorted).

Comment: Imagine that Value (1) is some number 12000 for example and Value (2) Is 15000 for example, etc... thats what I want to be sorted, Value (I), I being 1-20 where each iteration of Value (I) is a different value.

Comment: Your question has been edited with a link to the Wikipedia article on selection sort. That should help.

Comment: Eh it didn't really help me that much, I understand the basic concept but the syntax of ada is essentially my problem.

Comment: If you don’t understand Ada, click on the [ada] tag just under your question, then _info_, which should take you to a page which includes various learning resources.

Comment: Another source of information about Ada programming can be found at http://university.adacore.com/

Answer (score 1):

> The [*selection sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation) article didn't really help me that much; I understand the basic concept, but the syntax of Ada is essentially my problem.

Compare the [implementation cited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation) to [one in a language](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Selection_sort) with which you are familiar and review the resources cited in the Ada tag's [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ada/info) tab. If you encounter problems, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40831399/edit) your question to include a [*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Selection_Sort.ads**

```
package Selection_Sort is

   type Array_T is array (Natural range <>) of Integer; -- Array type
   procedure Sort (Array_To_Sort : in out Array_T); -- Sort the array
   procedure Print (Array_To_Print : in Array_T); -- Output the array

end Selection_Sort;
```

**Selection_Sort.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

package body Selection_Sort is

   procedure Sort (Array_To_Sort : in out Array_T) is
   begin
      for i in Array_To_Sort'Range
      loop
         declare
            minimum_index : Natural := i;
         begin
            for j in i+1 .. Array_To_Sort'Last
            loop
               if Array_To_Sort(j) < Array_To_Sort(minimum_index) then
                  minimum_index := j;
               end if;
            end loop;
            if minimum_index /= i then
               -- Swap
               declare
                  temp : Integer := Array_To_Sort(minimum_index);
               begin
                  Array_To_Sort(minimum_index) := Array_To_Sort(i);
                  Array_To_Sort(i) := temp;
               end;
            end if;
         end;
      end loop;
   end Sort;

   procedure Print (Array_To_Print : in Array_T) is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Array_To_Print: (");
      for i in Array_To_Print'Range
      loop
         Ada.Text_IO.Put(Integer'Image(Array_To_Print(i)));
      end loop;
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(")");
   end Print;

begin
   null;
end Selection_Sort;
```

**Main.adb**

```
with Selection_Sort;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Exceptions;

procedure Main is
   --My_Array : Selection_Sort.Array_T := (77,6,7,3,4,11,60,23,34,11);
   --My_Array : Selection_Sort.Array_T := (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
   My_Array : Selection_Sort.Array_T := (10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);
begin
   Selection_Sort.Print(Array_To_Print => My_Array);
   Selection_Sort.Sort(Array_To_Sort => My_Array);
   Selection_Sort.Print(Array_To_Print => My_Array);
exception
   when E: others =>
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Exception: " &
                             Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Information(E));
end Main;
```